# C++: How to find word with split? Regex

Tags: c++, regex, split, std, cpu-word

I need to find a serial number that is split with `"~"` characters and it may have from 10 to 30 letters in it.

Currently I am using this regex pattern: `"~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]~[A-Z]"`.

I need to change to it, so that it would search not only 10 letters, but any count up to 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(~[A-Z]){10,30}`

This should match any number of repetitions from 10 to 30.
(It is greedy by default, so it will match the longest possible string.)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need.